# Remove project.serviceclass name from servicestack url

Tags: rest, servicestack

I'm playing around with some of the ServiceStack demos and example code and I'm trying to see if there is a way to remove the need to have the project.serviceclass name in the url.  I used the nuget packages and created a ASP.NET MVC application called MvcMovieApp and created a SS service called `MovieService`.

```cs
[Route("/Movie")]
[Route("/Movie/{Name}")]
public class Movie
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}
public class MovieResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}

public class MovieService : Service
{
    public object Any(Movie request)
    {
        return new MovieResponse { Result = "The best Movie is " + request.Name };
    }
}
```

So to get the response I have to request:

> localhost/api/MvcMovieApp.MovieService/Movie/MyMovie

but I want to be able to make the request

> localhost/api/Movie/MyMovie

Is there a way to do this?

**Update**

```xml
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="api*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
</httpHandlers>
<location path="api">
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Update 2:

I was able to get it to work kind of.  I was trying to integrate ServiceStack in with an MVC application.  So my `Application_Start` has the following:

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    // RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Commenting out the MVC `RouteConfig` fixed the problem and lets me call the ServiceStack apis properly.  Here's the `RegisterRoutes` method.  I have the line so that MVC is supposed to ignore everything going to API.

```cs
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //routes.MapHttpRoute(
    //    name: "DefaultApi",
    //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    //);

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" }); //Prevent exceptions for favicon
}
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong? Thanks

Comment: It should work. Can you post the parts of your web.config that deal with the httpHandler paths?

Comment: It should work as expected, make sure you have the correct ASP.NET handler mappings configured, see: http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#rootpath

Answer (score 1):

The httpHandlers section can only appear once per config file. Also you don't need to to include path=api* in the httpHandler when it is a sub item of the location.

Use only this for your config:

```
<location path="api">
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```